# Scroll to an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the page to scroll just so that an element is visible.

Options I've tried:

- jQuery's `scrollTo`: the problem is that the page scrolls so that the element is on top (or at least it tries to do that, much like how this works: `<a name="xyz">` / `<a href="#xyz">`). I want the minimum amount of scrolling, so that the entire element is visible (and, if the element is too tall, work like the anchor there).
- `scrollIntoView`: awful. I want it to scroll smoothly (like `$.scrollTo($('#id1'), 'fast');`). Also, it doesn't seem to do what I want either.

Comment: Related: *[Scroll to an element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217962/scroll-to-an-element-using-jquery)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need to do is identify the position within the page of the element, top and bottom (and left/right if you are considering horizontal scrolling).  Then identify the current position of the viewport on the window, the scrollTop of the window should then be animated to whatever value will bring the other just in to view.

I just knocked up the following in this editor, so it's untested, but will give you the general idea for a plugin.

**Updated** - to show version that worked for the OP, as well as a smoother version

```
jQuery.fn.scrollMinimal = function(smooth) {
  var cTop = this.offset().top;
  var cHeight = this.outerHeight(true);
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var visibleHeight = $(window).height();

  if (cTop < windowTop) {
    if (smooth) {
      $('body').animate({'scrollTop': cTop}, 'slow', 'swing');
    } else {
      $(window).scrollTop(cTop);
    }
  } else if (cTop + cHeight > windowTop + visibleHeight) {
    if (smooth) {
      $('body').animate({'scrollTop': cTop - visibleHeight + cHeight}, 'slow', 'swing');
    } else {
      $(window).scrollTop(cTop - visibleHeight + cHeight);
    }
  }
};

$('#item').scrollMinimal();
```

Comment: This looks great. Doesn't work as-is, but I'm testing to see if I can make it work...

Comment: I replaced `$(window).animate({'scrollTop': the_number}, etc)` for `$.scrollTo(the_number, etc)` and it worked! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: The $(window).animate() call should have been $('body').animate() - your version using the scrollTop() is direct enough but not as smooth.  If you are actually using .scrollTo() then great, though that is a plugin now I believe.

Comment: Yeah, that's a plugin. I was just concerned about `$('body').animate` not working in some bizarre browser version, so I feel better leaving the scrolling to the plugin (which I'm sure is 105% tested in all browsers past, present, and future)

Comment: Think this should be `if (cTop < 0) {
        if (smooth) {
            pane.animate({ 'scrollTop': windowTop + cTop }, 'slow', 'swing');
        } else {
            pane.scrollTop(windowTop + cTop);
        }
    } else if`...

Comment: Just thought I would let you know this still works many years later, and it's really useful as there still isn't many other ways to do this.

Answer (score 15):

### There's a plugin for just what you need

I don't want to copy the code from blog post, because it can get outdated (due to upgrades). But anyway. You can find all details and code about the `.scrollintoview()` jQuery plugin on [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html).

### Usage

Contrary to `scrollTo()` plugin where you have to provide scrollable element this plugin only requires you to provide the element you'd like to scroll into view. Plugin finds nearest scrollable ancestor (with scrollbars) and scrolls to the element with animation, so user doesn't loose track of their position in the page.

The good thing is also that it won't scroll anything if element is already within visible boundaries of scrollable ancestor.

```
 $("ElementSelector").scrollintoview();
```

That's it most of the time. But if you need to set some additional settings, there are some you can change and provide custom behaviour:

```
scrollintoview: function (options) {
    /// <summary>Scrolls the first element in the set into view by scrolling its closest scrollable parent.</summary>
    /// <param name="options" type="Object">Additional options that can configure scrolling:
    ///        duration (default: "fast") - jQuery animation speed (can be a duration string or number of milliseconds)
    ///        direction (default: "both") - select possible scrollings ("vertical" or "y", "horizontal" or "x", "both")
    ///        complete (default: none) - a function to call when scrolling completes (called in context of the DOM element being scrolled)
    /// </param>
    /// <return type="jQuery">Returns the same jQuery set that this function was run  on.</return>
```

Comment: @AaronDigulla: It is better than my answer yes, and about five times the size, a proper plugin - rather than something just knocked up to provide a quick solution, as it states in the answer.  Sometimes a chunky plugin is less desirable than a small solution. *(Apologies for reviving a long dead post, just noticed this answer)*

Comment: @Orbling: but doesn't your solution also use an existing plugin `scrollTo()` which is even larger than mine? It is likely more flexible but serves a bit different purpose as well...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Not knocking your solution at all Robert, I gave it +1, just noting the differences, which is mainly a code size thing.  Mine only uses `.scrollTop()` which is a built-in method, no other plugins, AFAIK.  It was a long time ago, I only revived it due to getting a badge, which made me look, lol. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: Oh sorry. My bay. By glancing at your code I though you were using `scrollTo` plugin and not build in jQuery `scrollTop` function. Sorry about that. And I didn't feel like being knocked down. No. Just got me checking since I've seen a new comment. :) Great code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, jQuery scrolling element into viewport plugins alternative:

- [intoViewPort plugin](http://bernhardhaeussner.de/blog/82_jQuery_Plugin_intoViewport)
- [scrollIntoView plugin](http://arwid.github.com/jQuery.scrollIntoView)