# Selecting List Element (capturing down/up arrow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, dom-events, keypress

I have following HTML structure ('ul li' are rendered as drop-down/select)

```
<input id="input_city" type="text" />

<div class="suggestions">
 <ul>
  <li value="0" name="New York">New York</li>
  <li value="1" name="London">London</li>
  <li value="2" name="Paris">Paris</li>
  <li value="3" name="Sydney">Sydney</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Need JavaScript/jQuery code to capture down arrow key press event (on input) which will select first 'li' element

Consecutive down key select next 'li' elements; and up key select previous 'li' elements.

Comment: what do you mean by _selecting li element_?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Show us what you have tried and look this question answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902787/navigate-through-list-using-arrow-keys-javascript-jq

Answer (score 25):

Since your question is a little too vague, it's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish.

If you're trying to highlight the `li` elements, use this:

```js
var $listItems = $('li');

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    var $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected');
    var $current;

    if (![38, 40].includes(key)) return;

    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

    if (key == 40) { // Down key
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
        } else {
            $current = $selected.next();
        }
    } else if (key == 38) { // Up key
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
        } else {
            $current = $selected.prev();
        }
    }

    $current.addClass('selected');
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSKpT/

---

If you're just trying to set the value of your `input` field, change the last line to this:

```js
$(this).val($current.addClass('selected').text());
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSKpT/1/

Comment: Not sure about the question, but this answer is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Hi, and how do you push the list up and down if it's in an overflow div container?

Comment: thanks @Joseph its very good method , i am using your code and this is what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MousetrapJS](http://craig.is/killing/mice) for this. Here an example how you could implement the down key.
First add the class selected to the first list item.

```
Mousetrap.bind('down', function() {
    var next = $(".suggestions  li.selected").removeClass("selected").next();
    if (next.length) {
       next.addClass("selected");
    } else {
       $(".suggestions li").first().addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: `if(next)` will always return `true`, use `if(next.length !== 0)` instead.