# jQuery 2.1 | Navigate through non-contiguous links within a list with arrow keys

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, html-lists, arrow-keys

I want to navigate with arrow keys within a list that contains same-class links enclosed within **some** li, something like the following:

```
<ul>
<li class="linkTitle">LINKS BELOW</li>
<li class="linkHolder"><a class="link">LINK</a></li>
<li class="linkHolder"><a class="link">LINK</a></li>
<li class="linkTitle">LINKS BELOW</li>
<li class="linkHolder"><a class="link">LINK</a></li>
<li class="linkHolder"><a class="link">LINK</a></li>
<li class="linkHolder"><a class="link">LINK</a></li>
<li class="linkHolder"><a class="link">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code below works great for contiguous links and cycles up or down within the list, however, it breaks when confronted with an li that does not contain a link.

```js
$(function() {

    var $li = $('li'),
        
    $move = $(".move").click(function () {
        this.focus();
    });
    
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) {
            var inc = e.keyCode == 40 ? 1 : -1,
                move = $move.filter(":focus").parent('li').index() + inc;
            $li.eq(move % $li.length).find('.move').focus();
        }
    });
    
    $move.filter(':first').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class='move'>Link</a>
    </li>
    
</ul>
```

I tried but can't seem to make it work with non-contiguous links. A solution where you can only navigate (and cycle) within same-class links **regardless of amount and position of non-linked li** within a list would make my day!

**UPDATE**

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WWQPR/14/)** I'm working on which kind of works, the UP arrow key works as intended but stops focus once at top of list. The DOWN arrow key jumps focus to bottom of list. Cycling through links doesn't work either. In this sample, nextAll() and prevAll() seems to do the trick when encountering li with no link.

Comment: Won't tabbing do this without any code?

Comment: @j08691 I'm avoiding tabIndex in this list link array since my UI exploits arrow key navigation. Left and right arrow keys will cycle focus through link container headers while Up and Down arrow keys will cycle focus through link content within those containers. I don't want to maintain tabIndex values on dynamically added list/links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/wcyu7j8r/61/)** I concocted [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864516/navigate-through-multiple-lists-using-arrow-keys-jquery) from Stackoverflow. The non-linked li criteria mentioned above is simulated with a block element inserted between unordered lists. Menu navigation is based on accesskey functionality (accesskey + z); arrow keys; Tab key (partial); or mouse. Once any UL is highlighted (focused), left and right arrow keys allow navigating through ULs while up and down arrow keys navigate through each element within a highlighted UL. I added CSS to help distinguish which UL / li are focused:

**CSS**

```
body {-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;}

p {margin-top:10px;margin-left:4px;}
.ulholder{width:160px;height:200px;background:#AAA}
ul {background:#AAA}
ul.focused {background:#999}
ul:hover, ul:focus, ul:active {background:#999;}

li.selected {background:darkblue}
li:hover, li:focus, li:active {background:orange;}
li:hover a, li:focus a, li:active a {color:white;}
.list{cursor:pointer;}
.link {margin-left:10px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:darkblue}
.link:hover, .link:focus, .link:active {color:white;}
.linkfocused {color:white;}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ulholder"><p class="label">List 1</p>
<ul accesskey="z" tabindex="0">
<li class="list"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="link">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="list"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="link">Item 2</a></li>
<li class="list"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="link">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
<p class="label">List 2</p>
<ul tabindex="0">
<li class="list"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="link">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="list"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="link">Item 2</a></li>
<li class="list"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="link">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var $liSelected;
var $ulSelected;

$(function(){

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 // Make sure we have a ul selected

if($ulSelected) {

   if(e.which === 37) { // left arrow
   $('ul').prev().prev().addClass('focused').focus();
   }
   if(e.which === 39) { // right arrow
   $('ul').next().next().addClass('focused').focus();
   }

   if(e.which === 40) { // down arrow
   if($liSelected) {
   $liSelected.removeClass('selected');
   $liSelected.children('.link').blur();
   var $next = $liSelected.next('.list');

   if($next.length) {
   $liSelected = $next.addClass('selected');
   $next.children('.link').focus();

   } else {
   $liSelected = $ulSelected.children('li').first('.list').addClass('selected'); 
   $ulSelected.children('li').first('.list').children('.link').focus();
     }

   } else {
   $liSelected = $ulSelected.children('li').first('.list').addClass('selected');
   $ulSelected.children('li').first('.list').children('.link').focus();
     }

   } else if(e.which === 38) { // up arrow

   if($liSelected) {
   $liSelected.removeClass('selected');
   $liSelected.children('.link').blur();
   var $prev = $liSelected.prev('.list');

   if($prev.length) {
   $liSelected = $prev.addClass('selected');
   $prev.children('.link').focus();

   } else {

   $liSelected = $ulSelected.children('li').last('.list').addClass('selected');
   $ulSelected.children('li').last('.list').children('.link').focus();
     }

   } else {
   $liSelected = $ulSelected.children('li').last('.list').addClass('selected');
   $ulSelected.children('li').last('.list').children('.link').focus();
      }
   }

  }
});

$('ul .link').on('click focus', function() {
$('ul').removeClass('focused');
$('ul').find('.list').removeClass('selected');
$('ul').find('.link').removeClass('listfocused');
$(this).parent().addClass('selected');
$(this).parent().parent('ul').addClass('focused');
});

$('ul .list').on('click', function(){
$('.list').removeClass('selected');
$('.link').removeClass('linkfocused');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$(this).children('.link').focus().click().addClass('linkfocused');
});

$('ul').on('focus', function(e) {
$('ul .link').removeClass('linkfocused');
$('ul .list').removeClass('selected');
$('ul').removeClass('focused');
$ulSelected = $(this);
$(this).addClass('focused');
$liSelected = false;
});

});
```