# How to shift focus around list items with arrow keys, vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, focus, html-lists, arrow-keys

I am creating a small toDo app, and i want my users to be able to search through toDo items with arrow keys:
[ToDo app and list i would like to go through with arrows in upper right corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYtCF.png)

My code works but not as i intended, as it jumps through list items in some random way, but I don't understand why is it happening.

```
<div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Search Items...">               
                        <ul id="filter-ul">
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

Here's my html code in question, just an input text field for my search query and ul under it. But i think that there is a problem in my JS code:

```
let filter = document.getElementById("filter");
filter.addEventListener("keyup", navigateThroughList);

function navigateThroughList() {
  let firstItem = filterList.firstElementChild;
  // firstItem.focus();

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
      case "ArrowUp":
        if (document.activeElement == (filter || firstItem)) {
          filterList.lastElementChild.focus();
        } else {
          document.activeElement.previousSibling.focus();
        }
        break;


      case "ArrowDown":
        if (document.activeElement == filter) {
          firstItem.focus();
        } else {
          if(document.activeElement.nextSibling==null){
            firstItem.focus();
          }
          document.activeElement.nextSibling.focus();
        }
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

As I understood from couple of my errors, it has something to do with my input field not having sibling elements, but i protected myself from it with conditions in if{} brackets, or so I taught:
[error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeLW4.png)

It's driving me mad, because everything looks good logically, I'm missing something obvious probably as I am new to JavaScript. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which element is `filterList`? You adding `keydown` event on every keypress

Comment: filterList is just a list of list items(li) that i find when i type my search query

Comment: What about keydown,is that a problem?

Comment: Example with cursor navigation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984973/12918181

Comment: On every "keyup" in input field you adding new listener for "keydown", so "keydown" triggered then x times on ArrowUp/ArrowDown

Comment: So should i make just one event listener?