# CSS3-Animate elements if visible in viewport (Page Scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have added CSS animations to various div elements on my html page.But all the animations played at the same time & i can't see the animations at the bottom of the page.How can i make them play while i scroll down the page ?

Comment: Use JS, and if an element is *in Viewport* than add a class to all that elements. That class should trigger CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

## Using IntersectionObserver API

> The [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport.

Here's an example that triggers a [classList toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) when an Element is in viewport:

```js
const inViewport = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    entry.target.classList.toggle("is-inViewport", entry.isIntersecting);
  });
};

const Obs = new IntersectionObserver(inViewport);
const obsOptions = {}; //See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_options

// Attach observer to every [data-inviewport] element:
document.querySelectorAll('[data-inviewport]').forEach(el => {
  Obs.observe(el, obsOptions);
});
```

```css
[data-inviewport] { /* THIS DEMO ONLY */
  width:100px; height:100px; background:#0bf; margin: 150vh 0; 
}

/* inViewport */

[data-inviewport="scale-in"] { 
  transition: 2s;
  transform: scale(0.1);
}
[data-inviewport="scale-in"].is-inViewport { 
  transform: scale(1);
}

[data-inviewport="fade-rotate"] { 
  transition: 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
[data-inviewport="fade-rotate"].is-inViewport { 
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
Scroll down...
<div data-inviewport="scale-in"></div>
<div data-inviewport="fade-rotate"></div>
```

### Observer Options

To define another parent reference element use the `root` option inside the Observable options Object. At your disposition there's also `rootMargin` and the super useful `threshold` option

```js
const obsOptions = {
  // Default is null (Browser viewport). Set a specific parent element:
  root: document.querySelector('#someSpecificParent'),
  // add 40px inner "margin" area at which the observer starts to calculate:
  rootMargin: '40px', 
  // Default is 0.0 meaning the callback is called as soon 1 pixel is inside the viewport.  
  // Set to 1.0 to trigger a callback when 100% of the target element is inside the viewport,   
  // or i.e: 0.5 when half of the target element is visible:
  threshold: 0.5, 
};
```

See another [interesting use case that uses the IntersectionObserver API's `threshold`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65519620/383904) option.

Additional read:

- [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/)
- [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)
- [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/intersectionobserver) <s>IE browser</s>

---

Using the *native* IntersectionObserver API is the **most performant way** to tackle this problem.
If you want an idea on how we tackled similar needs in the past see [this answer with a small custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831113/383904) as an example.

Comment: Sorry, I created a .js file with the plugin above -> Added it to my  index.html -> Edited my .css file by adding .triggeredCSS3 to the .example_animations -> BUT now none of the animations work !! @Roko C. Buljan

Comment: Yeah,I included the plugin

Comment: I tried those things,but still not working !! @Roko C. Buljan

Comment: @Ajith I'm not sure what might go wrong, one last thought (without seeing your-end code) is that you might want to wrap the JS above in document.ready: `$(function(){ /*box inviewport code here*/ });`

Comment: @Ajith have you tried the new example? Also, can you create a jsBin demo so I can see what's wrong with your code? thanks

Comment: I don't know,but still not working.May be something went wrong somewhere.Any way thank you !! :) @ Roko C. Buljan

Comment: Cannot help unless you show some code. No problem. Happy coding.

Comment: I am beginner,this is the link to my complete html folder,you will get the html ,css & js in that.Please do check & if you have enough time ,let me know what went wrong :)    https://www.dropbox.com/s/6td9lylk1vak5bz/i%27m.rar?dl=0    @ Roko C. Buljan

Comment: @Ajith you're targeting elements with class `$(".box")` but in your HTML you don't have such class defined. I've added those classes but no animation so far... have not the time to go trough your whole code... See again my examples and start from there. Try to figure out what's wrong. I think its' some positioning issue... but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank You for having time to look at my page @Roko C. Buljan ,Yeah i'm trying to find out what's wrong.I'll let you know if i find it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you know how you would also remove the class so that when you scrolled back it would trigger the animation again?

Comment: @probablybest simply use `$(this).toggleClass("triggeredCSS3", !!px );` http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/tw6g2oeu/16/

Comment: On some web-browsers `$(window).height()` returns the document height instead of the viewport height unless you add a strict doctype as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103208/jquery-window-height-is-returning-the-document-height#answer-12902057).      
Maybe this is helpful to someone, as it took me sometime to figure that out.

Comment: @javijuol `<!DOCTYPE html>` is all it takes and since HTML5 I've never seen anyone use anything else.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just saying that if whatever reason you forget to put any DOCTYPE your web browser will render in quirks mode and so it will not work properly. Anyway, you should always add the DOCTYPE...

Comment: Wow! Nice functionality! Excited to try it!

Answer (score 48):

Still Javascript, but with this version you don't need to listen on scroll events.
Speed and performace is much better than check each time if an object is in the viewport.

Check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

With **Intersection Observer**, you can define a callback when an element is visible.

Options:
`root`: null << Set to null if you want it inside your viewport (visible area)
`threshold`: 0.3 << means 30% visibility. If you set 0.3, the callback is called once when the visibility reach at least 30% and once it is visible for less than 30%.

```js
function callbackFunc(entries, observer)
{
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    var txt = entry.target.id + " visibility: " + entry.isIntersecting;
    
    document.getElementById('log').appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
    document.getElementById('log').appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  });
}

let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.3
  };

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunc, options);

observer.observe(document.getElementById('firstBlock'));
observer.observe(document.getElementById('secondBlock'));
```

```css
#firstBlock {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: red;
}

#secondBlock {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: blue;
}

#log {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
First Block:
<div id='firstBlock'> </div>
<br><br><br>
Second Block:
<div id='secondBlock'> </div>
<div id='log'>Log: </div>
```

Comment: I feel like this should be accepted answer right now. The older example still works but is pretty outdated.

Comment: This should be the correct answer and shows good practices, avoids executing functions thousands of times.

Comment: What about deleting the second block visibility text when you scroll back to the first block? Seems like it shouldn't be too difficult...

Comment: Looks like its not still 100% precise, First block visibility becomes false even when I am seeing some portion of the first block

Comment: Guessing that's the `threshold: 0.3`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is using a scroll event listener

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
        const animatedBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("animated-box");
        const windowOffsetTop = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(animatedBoxes, (animatedBox) => {
            const animatedBoxOffsetTop = animatedBox.offsetTop;

            if (windowOffsetTop >= animatedBoxOffsetTop) {
                addClass(animatedBox, "fade-in");
            }
        });
    });
});

function addClass(element, className) {
    const arrayClasses = element.className.split(" ");
    if (arrayClasses.indexOf(className) === -1) {
        element.className += " " + className;
    }
}
```

```css
.animated-box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}

.fade-in {
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
            animation: fade-in 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
            transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
            transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Start scrolling down...
  
  <div class="animated-box">

  </div>
        
  <div class="animated-box">
        
  </div>

  <div class="animated-box">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="animated-box">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="animated-box">
  
  </div>
</div>
```