# Make <li> visible and fadein when it reaches viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a unordered list which i want to make to work in the following sense: li's that are not in viewport will be hidden (display:none), and when they reach the viewport i want them to become visible and fade in.
I figured i have to work with the scroll offsets but i cant figure it out how to make it for for each li.

```
<div class="my_list">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
</div>


.my_list ul li{
    height:550px; /*example height*/
}
```

Comment: Where is your viewport ? Or what do you mean when you state VIEWPORT ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, please give more details.

Comment: @EfiBN _The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page._ [W3chools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Answer (score 0):

http://xtianmiller.com/notes/animating-elements-when-they-appear-in-viewport/

This should help you understand.

Comment: or follow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462306/css3-animate-elements-if-visible-in-viewport-page-scroll

Comment: **Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link** so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Please don't just post links to external sites as answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i get it how it works, but i dont know how to go about doing it for each li since there is no id or anything to sepparate between them...