# Fade-in fade-out exactly once

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I want to make it so that elements with the class `fade` fade in when they are first visible on the screen then fade out when they leave the screen.

I want this animation to only happen once.

Below is what I have tried.

```
.fade {
   /* transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in;*/
    opacity: 0;   
  }

.fade.visible {
  transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', fade)
function fade()
{
  let animation=document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
   for (let i=0; i<animation.length; i++)
    {
     let windowheight=window.innerHeight;
     let top=animation[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
     if (top < windowheight)
     {
       animation[i].classList.add('visible');
     }
     else
     {
       animation[i].classList.remove('visible');
     }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) helpful.

Comment: no its not working, I want to add animation with scrolling

Comment: What did you try and what specifically goes wrong?

Comment: my code is working correctly I just need is that animation(fade-in and fade-out) apply on web page only one time not again and again when I scroll page.

Comment: My suggestion was to remove the event listener upon first scroll. Does that address your issue?

Comment: when I remove event listener then my web page show nothing its blank completely

Answer (score 1):

Use the **IntersectionObserver API** instead of expensive scroll listeners!

Here's an example that triggers a classList change when an Element is **in viewport** - based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27462500/383904), with the only difference that this one uses `classList.add` instead of `classList.toggle`:

```js
const inViewport = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("is-inviewport");
    }
  });
};

const Obs = new IntersectionObserver(inViewport);
const obsOptions = {}; //See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_options

// Attach observer to every [data-inviewport] element:
const ELs_inViewport = document.querySelectorAll('[data-inviewport]');
ELs_inViewport.forEach(EL => {
  Obs.observe(EL, obsOptions);
});
```

```css
[data-inviewport] { /* FOR THIS DEMO ONLY */
  width:100px; height:100px; background:#0bf; margin: 150vh 0; 
}

/* inViewport */

[data-inviewport="fade"] { 
  transition: opacity 2s;
  opacity: 0;
}
[data-inviewport="fade"].is-inviewport { 
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
Scroll down...
<div data-inviewport="fade"></div>
<div data-inviewport="fade"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than removing the event listener (which seems like doesn’t work for you for some reason) a simple change would be to add a global boolean flag which you toggle once after performing the animation. If the flag is true, just return early from the fade function

Something like this should work or at least be pretty close

```
let animationHappened = false; // flag to keep track of animation

function fade() {
  // only add the visible class if the animation hasn't happened yet, else return early
  if (animationHappened) return;

  let animation = document.querySelectorAll('.fade');

  for (let i = 0; i < animation.length; i++) {
    let windowheight = window.innerHeight;
    let top = animation[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (top < windowheight) {
      animation[i].classList.add('visible');
    } else {
      animation[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }
  }
  animationHappened = true;
}
```

This way `fade` should only animate once so long as `animationHappened` isn’t set to `false` again anywhere else in your code.

Comment: no its not working, with or without visible class

Comment: Sorry, are you saying the animation currently doesn’t happen at all now with your current code? I understood the question as, it works, but you only want it to work once.

Comment: yes! animation not happening after I add your code ,and  I want animation work only one time

Comment: That may be because there is no scroll handler here.

Comment: plz add scroll handler and paste code again plz

Comment: i add scroll handler it show only one section of web page

Answer (score 0):

First things first, it's pretty dang inefficient to do `querySelectorAll` on every scroll, so assuming all those elements are always there, let's just grab them all right away.

We can turn the node list into an array so we can easily remove items as we go. When an element is visible, we just add the visible class and remove it from the array. Then when the array is empty just remove the listener.

To make the items invisible again, we can push the visible items to a second array and perform a similar process. We only remove that listener after all items have faded in then faded out.

```js
const fadeInElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.fade'));
const makeInvisible = [];
let fadeInEmpty = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', fadeIn);
window.addEventListener('scroll', fadeOut);

function fadeIn() {
  const windowheight = window.innerHeight;
  for (let i = 0; i < fadeInElements.length; i++) {
    const element = fadeInElements[i];
    const topOfElement = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (topOfElement < windowheight) {
      element.classList.add('visible');
      makeInvisible.push(element);
      fadeInElements.splice(i, 1);
      if (fadeInElements.length === 0) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', fadeIn);
        fadeInEmpty = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function fadeOut() {
  const windowheight = window.innerHeight;
  for (let i = 0; i < makeInvisible.length; i++) {
    const element = makeInvisible[i];
    const topOfElement = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (topOfElement >= windowheight) {
      element.classList.remove('visible');
      makeInvisible.splice(i, 1);
      if (makeInvisible.length === 0 && fadeInEmpty)
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', fadeOut);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.visible {
  transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div class="fade">2</div>
<div class="fade">3</div>
<div class="fade">4</div>
<div class="fade">5</div>
<div class="fade">6</div>
<div class="fade">7</div>
<div class="fade">8</div>
<div class="fade">9</div>
<div class="fade">10</div>
```

Comment: @engr.hasnat great, I've added the code to make the items invisible again since I think that's what you wanted? Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.