# Checking the accuracy of visibility in viewport with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have created this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t58q6e1m/4/) which should log numbers ( <sub>those number doesn't represent anything - they just a flag which represents : " element has enter the viewport"</sub>). into a span when a specific element comes into view ( even if it's partly visible)

So I have a `relative` div with many gray cubes .One of the cubes is `orange` .

[image]

When I scroll the div - the orange cube starts to show  , and then I increase the numbers.

But the problem is that the numbers satrts to increase *before* the orange become visible :

As you can see here :

[image]

**Question**

I probably missing something but why does the numbers start before it actually visible ?

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function()
{

    var win = $(".d");

    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));


};

var i = 0;

$(".d").on('scroll', function()
{
    if ($(".orange").isOnScreen())
    {
        $("#counter").text(i++);
    }

});
```

Comment: What should those numbers represent?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Nothing. it just shows a flag that apparently the orange become visible. ( which is not).

Comment: Ohh OK ok thought you were about to ask an XY question :) got it

Comment: The algorithm you're using relies on `viewport` being the window, not the container element (`.d`).

Comment: @Juhana? `var win = $(".d");`

Comment: Yes, it should be `var win = $(window);`.

Comment: @Juhana ah, yes, that plugin was meant to be window, exactly that means that there are missing the parent offset calculations

Comment: @Juhana this would be valid for iframe. But I wnat it to be applied for a  absolute `div` which has a scroll.

Comment: @RoyiNamir probably not *exactly* what you want... but see this: http://jsfiddle.net/t58q6e1m/5/ basically taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831113/383904

Comment: Try changing the value of viewport right to   viewpost.right = win.width() - viewport.left;  It seems to be working.

Comment: What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/t58q6e1m/7/
I've modified your fiddle with a function that I use to detect if an element is visible

Comment: I've tried with FF and Chrome and both of them just showed the numbers when the orange div was completely visible. Did you tried with other browsers?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Yes now it's working . Have no idea why I thought it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `offset` to calculate the bounds of your orange boxes (*jQuery `.offset()` will get the current coordinates relative to the document.*), you should as well use `offset` to calculate the viewport bounds.

```
var viewport = {
    top: win.offset().top,
    left: win.offset().left
};
```

Your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/t58q6e1m/6/

Comment: That was my mistake.the offset is relative to document ( as opposed to `position`).

Comment: Yes. You could use `.position` to calculate position of your orange boxes, but then you would then compare the top with the `scrollTop` of the viewport.