# Styling of nav links on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an effect similar to: https://streetart.withgoogle.com/en/artist-stories

where the links in the navbar is being colored when the corresponding section is being shown, i.e. gallery link in navbar is being colered white when the corresponding section is shown in the viewport.

I've tried everything, and I cannot seem to figure out how it's done. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's called ScrollSpy. Bootstrap has such a plugin included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **[inViewport jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831113/383904)**
and create something like this:

```js
/**
 * inViewport jQuery plugin by Roko C.B. stackoverflow.com/questions/24768795/
 *
 * Returns a callback function with an argument holding
 * the current amount of px an element is visible in viewport
 * (The min returned value is 0 (element outside of viewport)
 * The max returned value is the element height + borders)
 */
;(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el) {
       function visPx(){
         var elH = $(el).outerHeight(),
             H = $(win).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? Math.min(elH, H-t) : (b<H?b:H)));  
       }
       visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));




// let's use it!
$aLinks = $("ul a");
$("[id^=art]").inViewport(function(px){
  if(px){
    $aLinks.removeClass("active");
    $("a[href=#"+ this.id +"]").addClass("active"); 
  } 
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
p{height:2000px;}
h1{
  padding:60px 0;
}
ul{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li a{
  padding:15px 10px;
  display:inlin-block;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.active{
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#art1">Article 1</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#art2">Article 2</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#art3">Article 3</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#art4">Article 4</a></li>  
</ul>

<section id="art1">
  <h1>Article 1</h1>
  <p>Article content 1</p>
</section >

<section id="art2">
  <h1>Article 2</h1>
  <p>Article content</p>
</section >

<section id="art3">
  <h1>Article 3</h1>
  <p>Article content</p>
</section >

<section id="art4">
  <h1>Article 4</h1>
  <p>Article content</p>
</section >
```

The principle is to use Link Anchors in your havigation `<a href="#page1">` elements and assign the same ID to the page sections `<section id="page1">`

now both clicking or scrolling the page will add an `.active` class to the anchor which section is visible on screen.