# jQuery - Detecting if element is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a script that gives different elements some animations when they appear in the screen.

Step one would be to detect when they come in the screen. But that doesn't seem to work.

What I tried:

-The `.visible()` selector, I quickly found out this does something else in jQuery.

-Different plugins, but I found that they do way more then I need, therefore I decided to write/ find something myself.

-My current script (I found it somewhere in a forum and decided to edit it to my needs) But It works a little strange.

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.blogcard ').isInViewport()) {
        $(this).addClass("test");
        console.log('success.')
    } else {
        console.log('No success.')
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to add a class to my `<div class='blogcard'>`.

Comment: Your logic is missing a couple of scenarios. Try Roko's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831113/519413)

Comment: try to get viewport position range and element position range first? Then, calculate is that element in the range.

Comment: Use Intersection Observer API to Detect if Element is in Viewport, details here – https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-detect-if-element-is-in-viewport-intersection-observer-api/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your use of "this" targets window not .blogcard element:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.blogcard ').isInViewport()) {
        //  Use .blogcard instead of this
        $('.blogcard').addClass('test');
        console.log('success.')
    } else {
        //  Remove class
        $('.blogcard').removeClass('test');
        console.log('No success.')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, hadn't noticed that. There's still a problem; Now it just gives all `.blogcards` the class test. Even if they are out of the viewport.

Comment: you need to remove the class if they are not in the viewport

Comment: I got Uncaught TypeError: $(...).isInViewport is not a function error, is it my Jquery version? if yes, what version I need to use so I can use this function? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the 'this' context into your $(window).scroll function. I did it by looping through elements, instead of just checking if a .class isInViewport()

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   $('.blogcard').each(function(i, el){

      if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
          $(this).addClass('test');
          console.log('content block is in viewport.', $(this))
      } 
   })

});
```

Removing the class was animating content around too much, so I took that out.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code ...

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.section3 ').isInViewport()) {
        $('.section3').addClass('its-now-view');
        alert('sction 3 is now in viewport');
    } else {
        $('.section3').addClass('its-now-view');
       alert('sction 3 is not in viewport');
    }
});
```

```css
.section{
 height:400px;
}
.section1{
  background-color: #333;
}
.section2{
  background-color: red;
}
.section3{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.section4{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Viewport demo</title>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/is-in-viewport/3.0.4/isInViewport.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="section section1">
  <p>Content of section 1</p>
</div>
<div class="section section2">
  <p>Content of section 2</p>
</div>
<div class="section section3">
  <p>Content of section 3</p>
</div>
<div class="section section4">
  <p>Content of section 4</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers. The posted function has a bug, `$(window).height()` is not providing the `viewport` height, but rather the entire document height. This `isInViewport` function returns always `true`. This is the proper implementation:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
  let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight; // <-- here

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```