# How can I run a function when an element enters the viewport?

Tags: jquery, counter

I have a counter stats, which works fine, but how can I write a condition that it should start only if the parent is in viewport? Maybe my syntax is wrong or I don't understand how to connect what I got. Any advice is appreciated.

This is what I got for now:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.numbers-inner').isInViewport()) {
    //then what?;

  } else {
    //else what?;
  }
});
$('.magPub, .pplHired, .yrsExp').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="numbers-inner stats">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="magPub">33708</span>+</li>
    <li>magazines published</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><span class="pplHired">247</span></li>
    <li>people hired</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><span class="yrsExp">17</span></li>

    <li>years of experience</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will fire animation when your parent becomes visible and will animate only once.

```js
let hasBeenAnimated = false;

$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight;

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

function animate() {
    $('.magPub, .pplHired, .yrsExp').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function(now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.numbers-inner').isInViewport() && !hasBeenAnimated) {
        hasBeenAnimated = true;
        animate();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 2000px">
  <h1>↓↓↓ SCROLL DOWN ↓↓↓</h1>
</div>
<div class="numbers-inner stats" style="background: red">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="magPub">33708</span>+</li>
    <li>magazines published</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><span class="pplHired">247</span></li>
    <li>people hired</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><span class="yrsExp">17</span></li>

    <li>years of experience</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Please note that `.isInViewport()` is not a `jQuery` function, but rather a custom function the user has implemented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220491). Also notice that the original function has a bug, this is the proper implementation:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
  let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight;

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has an [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) that would do just this. You setup the element to observe and it does the rest. In the below example we set the threshold to 50% (when 50% of your div shows, the function will be executed to begin the counting):

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.numbers-inner.stats');

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      $('.magPub, .pplHired, .yrsExp').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
          duration: 1500,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

let opts = {
  threshold: 0.5
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, opts);
observer.observe(target);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="numbers-inner stats">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="magPub">33708</span>+</li>
    <li>magazines published</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><span class="pplHired">247</span></li>
    <li>people hired</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><span class="yrsExp">17</span></li>

    <li>years of experience</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```