# Jquery / Add Class If same Data-Attribute Value is in Viewport

Tags: jquery

markup:

```
<div class="content" data-id="XX"></div>
<div class="media" data-id="XX"></div>
<div class="content" data-id="XY"></div>
<div class="media" data-id="XY"></div>
etc.
```

jquery:

```
        $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
            var elementTop = $(this).offset().top +600;
            var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

            var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

            return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
        };

        $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {

            dataid = $('.sticky-slider-content').data('id');
            
            if ($(dataid).isInViewport()) {
                $('.media').removeClass('active');
                $('.media[data-id="'+dataid+'"]').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

the media ist set to sticky. when content comes into viewport i want to give media with the same data-id a  class 'active'.

originally i came up with this, but i want to avoid the duplicates:

```
        $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {  
            if ($('.content[data-id="3a241cb2"]').isInViewport()) {
                $('.media').removeClass('active');
                $('.media[data-id="3a241cb2"]').addClass('active');
            }
            if ($('.content[data-id="6a91e7bb"]').isInViewport()) {
                $('.media').removeClass('active');
                $('.media[data-id="6a91e7bb"]').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick to determining the *active's* `data-id` value and query the related `.media` element, and using JavaScript's [**IntersectionObserver API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) (as in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27462500/383904)) to detect when an element enters or exits the viewport

```js
const inViewport = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // (This example is a proof of concept and might need optimization)
    const dataId = entry.target.dataset.id;  // i.e: "3a241cb2"
    const elsMedia = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id="${dataId }"]`);
    elMedia.classList.toggle("active", entry.isIntersecting);
  });
};

const Obs = new IntersectionObserver(inViewport);
const obsOptions = {}; //See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_options

// Attach observer to every [data-inviewport] element:
document.querySelectorAll('.content[data-id]').forEach(el => {
  Obs.observe(el, obsOptions);
});
```

Using **jQuery**,
and using the [inViewport micro jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831113/383904) which provides a callback to the designated elements collection with an argument `px` being the integer value of the visible height of each *intersecting* (in-viewport) element:

```js
/**
 * inViewport jQuery plugin by Roko C.B.
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831113/383904
 * Returns a callback function with an argument holding
 * the current amount of px an element is visible in viewport
 * (The min returned value is 0 (element outside of viewport)
 */
;(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el) {
       function visPx(){
         var elH = $(el).outerHeight(),
             H = $(win).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? Math.min(elH, H-t) : Math.min(b, H)));  
       }
       visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));


// Use like:
$(".content[data-id]").inViewport(function(px) {
  // `px` represents the amount of visible height
  if (px > 0) {
    // Is in viewport logic goes here
    const dataId = $(this).data("id");   // i.e: "3a241cb2"
    $(".media").removeClass("active");
    $(`.media[data-id="${dataId}"]`).addClass("active");
  } else {
    // Not in viewport logic goes here
  }
});
```

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @tuxedo you're welcome. Added another better example that uses the JS's Opserver API