# How to make sure an HTML element is in the screen when shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my **HTML** structure:

```
<body>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

    <div class='error'>error message</div>

    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
```

Here is my **CSS** code:

```
.error{
    display: none;
}
```

Here is my **Jquery** code:

```
// detect pressing enter on keyboard
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('.error').show();
    }
});
```

---

**What the above code does:** when user press `<enter>`, `<div>` will be shown.

**What I want:** when `<div>` shown, if it was in the screen then nothing, but if it was not in the screen, page scrolls and stops where `<div>` is in the screen, how can I do that?

*It should be noted that I don't want this:* `position: fixed;`

Comment: seems like a terrible way to use `br`

Comment: @NooBskie there is not `<br>` in reality, it is just a test.

Comment: Do you want the error div to scroll to the position of the window? Or the window scroll to the position of the div?

Comment: @RobinGordijn Second. the window scroll to the position of the div.

Comment: Have you tried ScrollTo() from jquery? Or take a look at this question, it maybe covers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685589/scroll-to-element-only-if-not-in-view-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

created [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcLa5Lyb/3/)

Modified your JS a bit, plz have a look

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('.error').show();
         $('.error')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can I set `20px` space between top and div ? actually I have a fixed header in my website, and in this case, div goes under the header.

Comment: @Sajad Yes you can, check my updated fiddle. I added padding to the error div. now it will leave 20px top padding

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this.

```
<div id='focus' class='error'>error message</div>

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('.error').show();
        document.getElementById('focus').scrollIntoview();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to `scrollIntoview()`. +1 upvote for you.